# Codable All Key Decode as Optional But Not Optional

Tags: ios, json, swift4, codable

Codable is easy to use and don't code samething to much

but when i use add new variable to the Codable after update the app

JSONDecoder throws KeyNotFoundError

if i declear variable as Optional, It will not throw KeyNotFoundError

but every thing is Optional is bad to use

how can i change the decode strategy to "if Key not exits, just ignore the variable" and every variable is not Optional and don't write echo variable for decodeIfPresent() ?

```
class Student: Coadable {
    var name:String = "TheDefaultIWent" ;
    ...ManyVarsInThisClass...
}
```

Comment: To ignore a non-optional variable when initializing a class is a contradiction in terms. A non-optional variable must get an initial value. To handle different cases I'd recommend to write a custom initializer. Or check the app version and decode into different struct / classes.

Comment: T.T this is the only way for Codable, -____- it looks i must write custom decoder for every variable

Comment: Use optional if the key will not exist is the correct way.